# about pratice linux sed

Tags: linux, sed

```
"caprometheusip" : {
      "id" : 11,
      "key" : "caprometheusip",
      "value" : "[fd02::100:ffff:ffff:ffff:e0]",
      "description" : "",
      "createTime" : 1660630139000,
      "updateTime" : 1644822836000
    },
```

There are the following fields in my json file. I want to replace this IP address, which corresponds to value, with ""

I tried to pass this command

```
Sed - i - e 's/ "[fd02:: 100: ffff: ffff: ffff: e0] "/ ""/' 1.json
```

After json executes, it has no effect

I wonder if it is because the Ip address starts with [. The sed command resolves to regular. If so, how should I modify the command

Comment: Please give this question a meaningful tile so others can find it when searching for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets are special characters and need to be escaped with `\`. Try this:

`sed -i -e 's/\[fd02::100:ffff:ffff:ffff:e0\]//g' 1.json`

Note that I also removed the extra spaces from the ip address in your expression and added the `g` flag in the substitue command in order to make sed replace all occurrences of the matched pattern.

Comment: OK,Thakns，I have another question. How to write the sed command if you want to change the [fd02:: 100: ffff: ffff: ffff: e0] ip to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I think you should spend five minutes reading an intro into `sed`, specifically the `s` command. Check this out: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-string-in-files/ for example. This will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets as `[]` are special characters

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak '/value/s/\[fd02::100:ffff:ffff:ffff:e0]//'
"caprometheusip" : {
      "id" : 11,
      "key" : "caprometheusip",
      "value" : "",
      "description" : "",
      "createTime" : 1660630139000,
      "updateTime" : 1644822836000
    },
```

Comment: It cannot be changed in this way. The IP address of this json file and other fields also starts with [. These remain unchanged. Only the IP address of this caprometheusip is modified to be empty